# sqlite extract sets of data where different rows within a set needs to have a certain value

Tags: sqlite

i have this structure - its series of games registered each game has min 2 players, but can have up to many people playing in the same game :

```
gamenumber,team,name,points

1000,team tower, Tom Smith, 100
1000,team vegas, John Little, 90
1000,team windy, Andy Cooper, 20

1001,team woods, Marie Jones, 120
1001,team windy, Andy Cooper, 40

1002,team woods, Marie Jones, 20
1002,team tower, Tom Smith, 11

1003,team tower, Tom Smith, 89
1003,team bars, Jonathan Swift, 21
1003,team hammock, Bill Mccain, 31
1003,team windy, Andy Cooper, -1
```

To extract all 'Tom Smith's' games i execute this query - which is working fine :

```
select id, gamenumber, team, name, points 
from `games` 
where gamenumber in ( 
  select gamenumber
  from `games`
  where name = 'Tom Smith'
  and team = 'team tower'
)
```

It extracts all the games tom' has played, and all the gameid's for the game that tom played so it generates 
a list of the full game.

What i would like is to be able to ex filter and say :

1) i want all games ( full game, meaning similar as above where it extracts all the gameid records on the game), where Tom Smith has played Andy Cooper - and only the games where he played Andy Cooper.

It should include games where Tom and Andy maybe played more than only the 2, but only games where these 2 has been playing together with each other.

the above data set the result im after would be :

```
gamenumber,team,name,points

1000,team tower, Tom Smith, 100
1000,team vegas, John Little, 90
1000,team windy, Andy Cooper, 20  

1003,team tower, Tom Smith, 89
1003,team bars, Jonathan Swift, 21
1003,team hammock, Bill Mccain, 31
1003,team windy, Andy Cooper, -1

1004,team woods, Andy Cooper, 70
1004,team tower, Tom Smith, 53
```

is it possible in a sqlite query to do that >

2) If im able to get the above list of games where the 2 played each other, i would also like to be able to do:
2.1) which games did Tom win against Andy ? ( Tom had the highest score within a gameid )

Result wished from dataset :

```
1000,team tower, Tom Smith, 100
1000,team vegas, John Little, 90
1000,team windy, Andy Cooper, 20  

1003,team tower, Tom Smith, 89
1003,team bars, Jonathan Swift, 21
1003,team hammock, Bill Mccain, 31
1003,team windy, Andy Cooper, -1
```

2.2) Summary of amount ofgames where Tom won the whole game, and Andy was playing in too - and summary of Tom's point in games where he plays Andy and was winner of game (position 1) - result wished from dataset :

```
2, 189
```

Would like it to be 3 seperate queries as i want to use them for different purpose - if its possible to do this in queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach is aggregation:

```
SELECT id, gamenumber, team, name, points 
FROM games
WHERE gamenumber IN (
    SELECT gamenumber
    FROM games
    WHERE
        (name = 'Tom Smith' AND team = 'team tower') OR
        (name = 'Andy Cooper' AND team = 'team windy')
    GROUP BY gamenumber
    HAVING MIN(name) <> MAX(name)
);
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Super that seems to generate a list of the games they played against each other but how can i correct that the above take in team+name into consideration ? in theory there can be the same name (just another person with the same name) in different teams ?

Comment: thanks alot ! and great with dbfiddle didnt know that existed !

Comment: Do you know if i also want to sum the matches that ex Tom Smith won - in games he played against Andy ? sum the total amount of points he got vs total amount of points Andy got - based on the extract above ? can that be put into 1 sql statement or how would i do that ?

Comment: @MdTp You should open a new question, as your new requirement differs substantially from what you asked originally.